# GoogleTest 1.7.0 `enum class` compile error

Tags: c++, enums, googletest, googlemock, enum-class

When I try and reference an `enum class` from a test fixture, it fails to compile with error `./gtest_mcp23s17.cpp:25:52: error: no type named 'HW_ADDR_6' in 'mcp23s17::HardwareAddress'
    TC_mcp23s17 _gpio_x(mcp23s17::HardwareAddress::HW_ADDR_6);
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^`

However, if I leave the reference in the test itself (*leaving ALL other code untouched*), it compiles without error and runs the test as you would expect. Is this a bug in GoogleTest, or what differentiates this scenario as far as the test is concerned?

**Test** *(generic)*: [COMPILES]

```
TEST(Construction, WHENObjectIsConstructedTHENAddressParameterIsStored) {
    TC_mcp23s17 gpio_x(mcp23s17::HardwareAddress::HW_ADDR_6);
    EXPECT_EQ(0x4C, gpio_x.getSpiBusAddress());
}
```

**Test Fixture:** [COMPILES]

```
TEST_F(SPITransfer, WHENPinModeHasNotBeenCalledTHENTheCallersChipSelectPinIsHigh) {
    TC_mcp23s17 gpio_x(mcp23s17::HardwareAddress::HW_ADDR_6);
    EXPECT_EQ(HIGH, getPinLatchValue(SS));
}
```

**Test Fixture** *(with gpio_x declared in fixture class)*: [FAILS]

```
class SPITransfer : public ::testing::Test {
  protected:
    TC_mcp23s17 gpio_x(mcp23s17::HardwareAddress::HW_ADDR_6);
    ...
}
TEST_F(SPITransfer, WHENPinModeHasNotBeenCalledTHENTheCallersChipSelectPinIsHigh) {
    EXPECT_EQ(HIGH, getPinLatchValue(SS));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class member can only be initialised with `=` or `{}`, not `()`. So either of these should work:

```
TC_mcp23s17 gpio_x=mcp23s17::HardwareAddress::HW_ADDR_6;
TC_mcp23s17 gpio_x{mcp23s17::HardwareAddress::HW_ADDR_6};
```

The rather unhelpful error message is because the compiler interprets the use of `()` to denote a function declaration, then gets confused because the thing inside the brackets isn't a type.

Comment: Wow, I feel super dumb. However, now that I fixed that, it's not displaying my tests. I'm still getting a valid success/error code after the test suite is called. Any ideas about this?

Comment: @Zak: I've no idea how Google Test works. If you have another question, ask another question.